# Html.fromHtml doesn't show low API 21 in android

Tags: android, html

I use **Html.fromHtml**. It bold in API 21 & higher but it doesn't show bold in low API 21. I only want to do bold **R.string.str_taker_name** (NOT: **edtText.getName()**).  How to do bold this text for every API.

```
takerName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_taker_name);
takerName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_name) +"</b>: "+ edtText.getName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
TextView txt_taker_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
txt_taker_name.setTypeface(boldTypeface);
```

Or set the attribute in xml:

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

In this case you can try this function:

```
public static SpannableStringBuilder makeSectionOfTextBold(String text, String textToBold){
        SpannableStringBuilder builder=new SpannableStringBuilder();
        if(textToBold.length() > 0 && !textToBold.trim().equals("")){
            String testText = text.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            String testTextToBold = textToBold.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            int startingIndex = testText.indexOf(testTextToBold);
            int endingIndex = startingIndex + testTextToBold.length();
            if(startingIndex < 0 || endingIndex <0){
                return builder.append(text);
            }
            else if(startingIndex >= 0 && endingIndex >=0){
                builder.append(text);
                builder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startingIndex, endingIndex, 0);
            }
        }else{
            return builder.append(text);
        }
        return builder;
  }
```

and use it like:

```
YourActivity.makeSectionOfTextBold(edtText.getName(), getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_name));
```

and set the result to the `TextView`

Hope it helps!!!